# Android Studio 2, Percent Layout problems

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0, android-percentrelativelayout

I'm using PercentRelativeLayout in my apps (you have to specifically import support for this layout). With this layout, you don't have to specify layout_width and layout_height (you use app:layout_heightpercent instead), and this worked fine on the previous Android Studio version. But now that I've updated to the new Android Studio 2, I get errors, it says I must define the default height and width values. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly a solution, but it does prevent the error.

I have just been defining the layout_width and layout_height as either 0dp or wrap_content and then set my layout_widthPercent and layout_heightPercent to whatever percent I want.

It is important to note that if you set the non-percent width and height to wrap_content alongside setting percents, then views larger than the allowed percentage values will instead be resized using wrap_content rules.  I have no clue if something similar happens when using 0dp vs wrap_content.